# I want to generate random limited 20 record of sql but not repeat using php code

Tags: php, mysql

I make website using php code and mysql.
total record in database 77.
i see only 20 record of database using php.
i using this code

```
$sql = "Select * from record where Limit 20";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
while($myrow = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr><td>" . $myrow["id"] . "</td><td>" . $myrow["name"] . "</td></tr>";
}
```

**record show is**

```
ID         Name
1          ali1
2          ali2
3          ali3
........
20         ali20
```

but i see record random and not repeat any record
i show record this

```
ID         Name
3          ali3
55         ali55
22         ali22
60         ali60
```

how can this

Answer (score 1):

Try this one to get random 20 records from table:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 20;
```